# I need my counter to stop counting and display a toast when it reaches 510

Tags: java, android, textview, listener

This is the math part at the moment, i have one of these for each text view element, and it counts fine, all i need is for the numbers in all of the text views to stop counting when the total reaches 510 and all the others to stop counting when they reach 252 individually

when the total reaches 510 and/or when the individual values reach 252 i want a toast displaying "Highest number reached" or something like that

This is Java if anyone doesn't know, and it's in android studio

```
private View.OnClickListener hpListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {

    // Spinner element
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.evval);
    // TextView element
    TextView HPtx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hpval);
    TextView atttx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attval);
    TextView deftx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.defval);
    TextView satx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saval);
    TextView sdtx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sdval);
    TextView spdtx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spdval);
    TextView totaltx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalval);

    // Ev values
    int add = Integer.parseInt(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

    // Calculation
    int HP = Integer.parseInt(HPtx.getText().toString());
    int att = Integer.parseInt(atttx.getText().toString());
    int def = Integer.parseInt(deftx.getText().toString());
    int sa = Integer.parseInt(satx.getText().toString());
    int sd = Integer.parseInt(sdtx.getText().toString());
    int spd = Integer.parseInt(spdtx.getText().toString());
    int hptotal = HP + add;
    int total = hptotal + att + def + sa + sd + spd;

    // Value calculations
    DecimalFormat addHPFormat = new DecimalFormat("000");
    DecimalFormat addtotalFormat = new DecimalFormat("000");
    HPtx.setText(addHPFormat.format(hptotal));
    totaltx.setText(addtotalFormat.format(total));
    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
private View.OnClickListener hpListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {

    // Spinner element
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.evval);
    // TextView element
    TextView HPtx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hpval);
    TextView atttx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attval);
    TextView deftx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.defval);
    TextView satx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saval);
    TextView sdtx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sdval);
    TextView spdtx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spdval);
    TextView totaltx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalval);

    // Ev values
    int add = Integer.parseInt(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

    // Calculation
    int HP = Integer.parseInt(HPtx.getText().toString());
    int att = Integer.parseInt(atttx.getText().toString());
    int def = Integer.parseInt(deftx.getText().toString());
    int sa = Integer.parseInt(satx.getText().toString());
    int sd = Integer.parseInt(sdtx.getText().toString());
    int spd = Integer.parseInt(spdtx.getText().toString());
    int hptotal = HP + add;
    int total = hptotal + att + def + sa + sd + spd;

    if (total >= 510 || add >= 253 || att >= 252 || def >= 252 || sa >= 252 || sf >= 252 || spd >= 252) {
         // Replace MainActivity.this with your context
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Highest number reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return;
    }

    // Value calculations
    DecimalFormat addHPFormat = new DecimalFormat("000");
    DecimalFormat addtotalFormat = new DecimalFormat("000");
    HPtx.setText(addHPFormat.format(hptotal));
    totaltx.setText(addtotalFormat.format(total));
    }
};
```

Comment: This worked somewhat perfectly, only problem is that the spinner can increase the value by up to 12 every time, so if the values land at, lets say 261, the toast will pop up, but i need it to stop counting before it reaches 253

Comment: That means you also want to check the spinner evval also?

Comment: If yes, I modified answer for you :)

Comment: I don't think that's right, you see the spinner value doesn't change, it looks like this:

Ok so i can't get the code to show right, but the spinner is a List<Integer>, with the values 1, 4, 8 and 12.

Answer (score 0):

Just Place this in your code after total:

```
if(total >= 510 || hp >=252 || att >=252 || def >=252 || sa >=252 || sd >=252 || spd >=252)
    Toast.makeText(this,"highest Number Reached",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else {
 DecimalFormat addHPFormat = new DecimalFormat("000");
    DecimalFormat addtotalFormat = new DecimalFormat("000");
    HPtx.setText(addHPFormat.format(hptotal));
    totaltx.setText(addtotalFormat.format(total));
}
```